# How did Coop know about Brand and Edmund?

Tags: interstellar

In the film, Coop finds out that Brand and Edmund have a history by asking TARS, who mentions he has a discretion setting, which then tells Coop something was between them. But why did Coop think to ask TARS? I imagine I missed something at NASA when they were discussing the 12 explorers.

Comment: I got the impression that he guessed it based on how she spoke of him, and how she irrationally wanted to go to visit his planet, rather than Mann's, despite Mann's being the better choice...but I might be remembering the scenes in the wrong order.

Comment: The scene where she wanted to go to Edmund's planet over Mann's was after they had left Miller's. This is where it is confirmed, but Coop asks TARS just before they go into hypersleep on the way to Saturn.

Comment: Related: [Why & how did Cooper suspect that Amelia Brand had intimate feelings for Wolf Edmunds in Interstellar?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/41569/49)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In fact it's not what she says but how she says it: on the ship, the first time Cooper asks her to tell him about Edmund, she says a purposely very simple description ("he's a physicist") but she smiles to herself.  Cooper catches this smile and that's his clue that she has feelings for Edmund.

In the [screenplay](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1623160588) there are some non-dialogue directions in an exchange between Brand and Cooper that support this:

> BRAND
>
> Laura Miller's first. She started our biology program.
>
> *She shows him a red world, just a tiny dot.*
>
> And Wolf Edmunds is *here*.
>
> *Cooper hears something in her voice.*
>
> COOPER
>
> Who's Edmunds?
>
> BRAND
>
> *(fondly)*
>
> Wolf's a particle physicist.

Comment: I think your answer is right and there are some non-dialogue bits in the [published screenplay](http://www.amazon.com/Interstellar-Complete-Screenplay-Selected-Storyboards/dp/1623160588) that support it, is it OK if I edit your post just to add a quote from the screenplay at the end, or would you rather I write up my own answer?

Comment: Either way is fine - I'm new here so don't know the conventions.

Comment: Figured there was something in the script that might give added context. Must've missed it on the first watch.

Answer (score 3):

[Disclaimer: I saw the movie three weeks ago, so I might be misremembering this]

The NASA people, as portrayed in the movie, have an habit of referring to each other and themselves in a professional, scholarly manner. When Cooper is being interrogated by TARS, Brand refers to herself as "Dr. Brand", not "Amelia Brand", and afterwards Cooper always addresses and refers to her as "Brand" or "Dr. Brand", even when they go through enough stuff together that they could reasonably get on a first-name basis. Mann is invariably addressed as "Dr. Mann", even in situations that do not warrant it (i.e., when Mann and Cooper are fighting, or when Mann is about to open the imperfectly-docked airlock). Then, Brand goes and refers to Edmunds as "Wolf". That's something noteworthy in this type of "Dr. this an Prof. that" environment.

Comment: Good point. I hadn't noticed she referred to him by his first name.

Comment: This is probably the strongest evidence of a personal relationship, backed by dialog. Well done!

Answer (score 2):

Cooper is being nosy in the beginning and asks TARS about Edmund-Amelia based on how Amelia talks about Edmund.
Later when Amelia is being irrational about going to Edmund's planet, Cooper brings it up (because it is no more "none of his business"). Cooper would like to go to Mann's for his family and Amelia wants to go to Edmund's for love. But Cooper wins because Mann's is the logical choice.

Comment: Are there any quotes you could give that show how Amelia spoke about Edmund? I don't know if there is a script somewhere online, but I can't remember what kind of things she said about Edmund specifically (I remember her saying something like 'they were the best of us' when referring to the 12).